# populate data in textview on load

Tags: android, tabs

I am trying to load data into textviews on load. My app uses fragments and has three tabs. I am able to load data into the first two tabs, but I get a null pointer exception when I try to load data into the 3rd tab. Here's the code:

```
public void readAndLoadDataFromFile()
{
    String[] fieldNamesInFile = new String[50];
    double[] valuesInFile = new double[50];
    // read all the data from file
    readAllDataFromFile(fieldNamesInFile, valuesInFile);

    // Tab 1
    double value1 = valuesInFile[Arrays.asList(fieldNamesInFile).indexOf("Field1")];
    // copy the data into the fields
    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setText(String.valueOf(value1)); // OK

    // Tab 2
    double value2 = valuesInFile[Arrays.asList(fieldNamesInFile).indexOf("Field2")];
    // copy the data into the fields
    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2)).setText(String.valueOf(value2)); // OK

    // Tab 3
    double value3 = valuesInFile[Arrays.asList(fieldNamesInFile).indexOf("Field3")];
    // copy the data into the fields
    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3)).setText("123"); // null pointer exception


}
```

The layout XML file for Tab 3 is as follows (first two tabs are similar):

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text 3:"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="25"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you upload your xml layout?  And change it to .setText("text") just so we know it is an issue with the findViewById returning null

Comment: Added XML and tried setText("123"), same error. Not sure what's so special about Tab 3. Other two tabs are OK. If I swap out the layouts for Tabs 2 & 3, then I can write in Tab 2 (but with layout for Tab 3), but not in the layout in Tab 3 (formerly used in Tab 2).

Comment: The error doesn't make much sense from what I see, are you sure that you haven't declared another view with id="editText3"?  

Another question, do you have different .xml files for different screen types?

Comment: Just tried in debugger, findViewById(R.id.editText3) is returning null. This does not happen for first two tabs.

Comment: Yes, 3 different XMLs (similar layout, though) with different ids.

Comment: If you have 2 XML files for one layout, say layout.xml in the /layout/ and /layout-large/ folder, each view needs to have the **same** id tags in both files.

Comment: I meant 3 different xmls for the three tabs. Could it be that I am not waiting long enough for the third tab to load?

Comment: No, you can get the EditText instance in onCreate().  Is your myScrollView inflated through your code and added to the containing view?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the project simply needs the R file rebuilt.  You could try the "Clean" option in Eclipse (select Project -> Clean and select your project).  You also might check the R file to see if the entry is there.  The R file is located in the `gen` directory.  If it's not, you could try deleting the R file and letting it rebuild when you compile again, and see if it appears.

Another thing to check is to be sure that the R file being accessed isn't the Android R file.  Check your imports for that, or force it by changing your line to `((EditText) findViewById(com.yourproject.app.R.id.editText3)).setText("123");` with the `com.yourproject.app` part set to your package name.  Doing that will assure that you're getting the right R file.

Comment: Tried cleaning all projects several times, and also tried to explicitly using findViewById(com.yourproject.app.R.id.editText3)).setText("123"); as suggested. Still, no luck. The problem seems to be something special about Tab 3. If I switch what I load in Tab 2 vs Tab 3, the content of former tab 3 loads fine, but the content of former Tab 2 isn't loaded (null pointer exception). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed (hacked) the problem by forcing the navigation to go to the particular tab and loading the views.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(2); // go to Tab 3

double value3 = valuesInFile[Arrays.asList(fieldNamesInFile).indexOf("Field3")];
// copy the data into the fields
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3)).setText("123"); // no more null pointer exception
```

Not proud of myself, but at least it solves the problem for now.